# Closed form of recursion an ceiling function

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am trying to find a closed form for the recursion:
$a_n=6a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2}$ with the conditions $a_0=1, a_1=3$

My attempt:
Let's assume there exists $c$ such that $a_n=c^n$. (1)
Next step is to rewrite $a_n=6a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2}$ regarding our assumption (1), thus I get:

$c^n=6c^{n-1}-4c^{n-2}$
Dividing by $n-2$ yields, $c^2=6c-4$
Next step is to solve the equation, $c_1= 3-\sqrt5, c_2=c_1= 3+\sqrt5$.

Now, $\lambda_1 c_1^n+\lambda_2 c_2^n$ should also be able to represent the recursion.

The last step is to calculate the coefficients $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$. For that, we use the initial condition given ant the beginning.
Thus, we get the euations:

$\lambda_1+\lambda_2=1$

$\lambda_1 (3-\sqrt5)+\lambda_2 (3+\sqrt5)=3$

By solving I get $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2=\frac{1}{2}$

Thus, $a_n=\frac{1}{2} (3-\sqrt5)^n+\frac{1}{2} (3+\sqrt5)^n$

That's how far I got.

Now someone told me that $a_n$ can also be written as $a_n=\lceil \frac{(3+\sqrt5)^n}{2} \rceil$, where $\lceil . \rceil$ denotes the ceiling function.

My question: Why can $a_n$ be written in that way using the ceiling function? Is this some special case, or is it possible to write other the closed form of other recursions to in such a way?

Comment: Notice that $0<\frac{1}{2} (3-\sqrt5)^n < 1$ and $a_n$ is an integer...

Comment: @Sil You mean $a_n- \frac{1}{2}(3-\sqrt5)^n=(3+\sqrt5)^n$, alpplying the ceil function gives $\lceil a_n- \frac{1}{2}(3-\sqrt5)^n \rceil = \lceil (3+\sqrt5)^n\rceil$. The left side is equal to $\lceil a_n \rceil - \lceil \frac{1}{2}(3-\sqrt5)^n \rceil $ which is considering your hint is equal to $a_n$, right?

Comment: You are missing a factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ but yeah that is the idea. Notice however that $\lceil n-x \rceil\neq \lceil n \rceil -\lceil x\rceil$ in general. Instead $\lceil n-x \rceil=\lceil n \rceil +\lceil-x\rceil=\lceil n \rceil -\lfloor x\rfloor$ (we can switch the sign to convert ceiling to floor function). I am also sure there is a duplicate for this but I haven't found suitable one yet (similar thing happens for Fibonacci sequence, but there it is a rounding to nearest integer instead of ceiling).

Comment: @Sil Thank you very much